# Access S3 (KMS Encrypted) objects through VPC endpoint using CURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc, amazon-kms, vpc-endpoint

I have a custom Operating system running on EC2 inside a private VPC. The O.S doesn't have support of AWS CLI and  sdk, **it has only curl**. I have configured a VPC-endpoint to access S3 objects and am able to download objects which are not KMS encrypted. But, the S3 bucket is KMS encrypted, so I need help in accessing s3 (KMS encrypted) objects using curl.

I believe, authorization  header is not required for curl to access the objects because my VPC-Endpoint policy has permissions "kms:*, s3:*" in it's policy.

NOTE:

1. VPC-Endpoint--> is a Gateway endpoint to access S3
2. KMS Key----> is an AWS managed key

I believe, I have given enough info.

Comment: I think you will also need a VPC endpoint for KMS - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/kms-vpc-endpoint.html

Comment: An endpoint policy controls which AWS principals can use the endpoint to access an AWS service. It doesn't override or replace the need for identity-based policies or resource-based policies.